# Powershell, Map network drive if does not exists

Tags: powershell, dictionary

I'm just starting with power shell and scripting and I'm still at the absolute beginning. I would like to ask for your advice and suggestions.

With Powershell, I want to provide my users with a script that they can use to manually connect their network drives as needed.
The drive letters are always preset: T, U, V, W, X.
Before connecting, I would like to check if the drives are already connected or in use. If necessary, map them.
How would you solve that?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/626bb81a-00ba-4239-ad0a-fec32546350a/check-if-drive-exists-if-not-map?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [New-PSDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) with the `-Persist` option. We also use [Get-PSDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-6) and some logic to determine if they are in use and mapped to the right location.

```
$Name = "T"
$Path = "\\Server01\MyShare"

$MappedDrive = (Get-PSDrive -Name $Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

#Check if drive is already mapped
if($MappedDrive)
{
  #Drive is mapped. Check to see if it mapped to the correct path
  if($MappedDrive.DisplayRoot -ne $Path)
  {
    # Drive Mapped to the incorrect path. Remove and readd:
    Remove-PSDrive -Name $Name
    New-PSDrive -Name $Name -Root $Path -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"
  }
}
else
{
  #Drive is not mapped
  New-PSDrive -Name $Name -Root $Path -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"
}
```